# How to wait some seconds before the form is closing?

Tags: c#, winforms

Maybe my whole logic is wrong, but I want that if the user is closing the form in the middle of a processing first update the richTextBox and delete the current working folder on and make some more stuff like waiting 3 seconds then when finishing all these tasks close the form.

This code does nothing but just closing the form. and instead, I want it to wait few seconds for example 3 seconds show in the logger a message then after some seconds for example 3 close the form.

maybe I can use some dialog, but I want that if the user decided to close the form, then it will be considering as a cancellation.

in most of the application there is a dialog, but does dialog pause the whole form processes before the user decide what to do?

at the top of the form

```
private bool isCancelling = false;
```

then

```
private async void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (isCancelling)
    {
        // Already cancelling, let it continue
        return;
    }

    if (processingFrames)
    {
        // Set the flag to indicate that we are cancelling
        isCancelling = true;

        // Trigger the cancellation
        if (cancellationTokenSource != null)
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }

        // Wait for a few seconds before closing the form
        int waitTimeInSeconds = 3; // You can adjust this as needed
        for (int i = waitTimeInSeconds; i > 0; i--)
        {
            logger.Log($"Cancelling in {i} seconds...", Color.Yellow);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }

        // Log the cancellation and close the form
        logger.Log("Session Cancelled at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"), Color.Red);
        logger.Log("", Color.Black);

        DeleteCurrentSession(); // Delete the current session folder

        e.Cancel = false; // Allow the form to close
    }
    else
    {
        // If not processing frames, allow the form to close immediately
        DeleteCurrentSession(); // Delete the current session folder
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
}
```

another problem is to update the logger when the form is closing because everything is get disposed so the richTextBox1 is also disposed then I get a message I can update it in the form1 closing event:

inside the LogInternal event: on this line

```
_richTextBox.SelectionStart = _richTextBox.TextLength;
```

and the Logger class:

I want it to update the richTextBox before closing the form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public class Logger
    {
        private readonly RichTextBox _richTextBox;
        private bool saveToFile; // Added a flag to indicate whether to save to a file
        private string logFilePath = "";

        public Logger(RichTextBox richTextBox, bool saveToFile = false)
        {
            _richTextBox = richTextBox;
            this.saveToFile = saveToFile;

            // Initialize the log file path in the constructor
            InitializeLogFilePath();
        }

        private void InitializeLogFilePath()
        {
            string folderName = "Logs"; // Replace with the desired folder name
            string fileName = "log.txt"; // Replace with the desired file name
            // Set the log file path without creating the directory or file
            logFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath, folderName, fileName);
        }


        public void Log(string message, Color textColor)
        {
            if (_richTextBox.InvokeRequired)
            {
                _richTextBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    LogInternal(message, textColor);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                LogInternal(message, textColor);
            }
        }

        private void LogInternal(string message, Color textColor)
        {
            _richTextBox.SelectionStart = _richTextBox.TextLength;
            _richTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
            _richTextBox.SelectionColor = textColor;
            _richTextBox.AppendText(message + Environment.NewLine);
            _richTextBox.SelectionColor = _richTextBox.ForeColor;

            // Scroll to the caret (the end)
            _richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();

            if (saveToFile)
            {
                SaveToFile(message); // Save to a file if the flag is set
            }
        }

        private void SaveToFile(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                // Ensure the directory exists, and create it if it doesn't
                string folderName = "Logs"; // Replace with the desired folder name
                string fileName = "log.txt"; // Replace with the desired file name

                // Application.LocalUserAppDataPath
                logFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath, folderName, fileName);

                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath, folderName));

                // Append the message to the log file
                File.AppendAllText(logFilePath, message + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions related to file I/O here
                Console.WriteLine("Error saving to log file: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public string LogFilePath()
        {
            return logFilePath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Async void" FormClosing handler can't give you guarantee that all its stuff will be executed actually before form is closed. Remove "async". Instead of await Task.Delay use Task.Delay(...).Wait() or Thread.Sleep(...).

Comment: This doesn't sound like a terribly difficult problem. Use a timer a close the form when the timer goes off.

Comment: @Enigmativity but where in the code you start the timer? when the user click the right top corner x on the form to close it then everything is disposed you can't update the richTextBox.

Comment: Why you need to log to RichTextBox when form closing? User won't see this messages "Cancelling in...", "Session cancelled" etc

Comment: That's a dependency issue you've experienced. You strongly bound your Logger to some instance of RichTextBox control. No control = no logging. Make Logger independent. With overloads for example: LogTo(string file) { ... } and LogTo(RichTextBox rtb) { ... }. When you need both logging outputs - call both. When you close form and need only log to file - skip call of LogTo(RichTextBox)

Comment: What is the purpose for waiting for exactly 3 seconds? The clean-up work might last more or less than 3 seconds. If it lasts more, you want it to be aborted after 3 seconds? If it lasts less, you want to delay the closing for no reason? Also what do you want to happen if the user clicks again the "Close" button during this 3 seconds timespan? Do you want to restart the 3 seconds countdown, ignore the click, or close the form immediately?

Comment: Using a timer imo is terrible programming. Use something like a mutex or task wait and edge trigger the close completion. Usually people implement a loading spinner animation to make this wait apparent to the end user and perhaps a status bar text.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of a form that closes 3 seconds after the user clicks the close form button - unless they cancel before the 3 seconds is up.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Stopwatch _closingStopwatch = null;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _closingTimer = null;
    private Button _closingCancelButton = null;
    
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        _closingCancelButton = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Cancel Close",
            Enabled = false,
            Width = 160,
        };
        
        _closingCancelButton.Click += (s, a) =>
        {
            _closingTimer.Enabled = false;
            _closingStopwatch = null;
            _closingCancelButton.Enabled = false;
            _closingCancelButton.Text = "Cancel Close";
        };
        
        this.Controls.Add(_closingCancelButton);

        _closingTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer()
        {
            Interval = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1).TotalMilliseconds,
            Enabled = false,
        };
        
        _closingTimer.Tick += (s, a) =>
        {
            var secondsToCloseAt = 3.0;
            if (_closingStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds >= secondsToCloseAt)
            {
                _closingCancelButton.Enabled = false;
                _closingTimer.Enabled = false;
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                _closingCancelButton.Text = $"Closing in {secondsToCloseAt - _closingStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds:0.0} seconds.";
            }
        };

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_closingStopwatch == null)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            _closingStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            _closingCancelButton.Enabled = true;
            _closingTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
}
```

There is interplay between a `Timer` and a `Button` to orchestrate the 3 second delay.

Before closing and after cancelling:

[image: Before Cancel]

Before cancelling:

[image: During Cancel]

---

Here's an Rx version:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button _closingCancelButton = null;
    private IDisposable _closingSubscription = null;
    
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        _closingCancelButton = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Cancel Close",
            Enabled = false,
            Width = 160,
        };
        
        _closingCancelButton.Click += (s, a) =>
        {
            _closingSubscription.Dispose();
            _closingSubscription = null;
            _closingCancelButton.Enabled = false;
            _closingCancelButton.Text = "Cancel Close";
        };
        
        this.Controls.Add(_closingCancelButton);
        
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
    
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
    if (_closingSubscription == null)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        _closingCancelButton.Enabled = true;
        _closingSubscription =
            Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))
                .Take(30)
                .Select(x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0 - x / 10.0))
                .ObserveOn(this)
                .Do(x => _closingCancelButton.Text = $"Closing in {x.TotalSeconds:0.0} seconds.")
                .LastAsync()
                .Subscribe(x => { }, () => this.Close());
        }
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity did you choose a Timer control on purpose due to some limitation, eg Await Task in a [STAThread] or the Main thread shows the UI,  or why did you not to do it with a `Sleep`?

Comment: @JeremyThompson - You have to multithread to make `Sleep` work otherwise you hang the UI. And awaiting in a `void async` doesn't handle exceptions well. This is just a place where a classic timer works well.

Comment: Not a fan of using the `DateTime.Now` for measuring time intervals. The computer clock can be adjusted at any time, rendering the measurement invalid. I would prefer to use a [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Fair point. I've refactored to use `Stopwatch`.